# C Program to Append Letter(s) to End of File

Tags: c, file, file-io, while-loop, append

Open an existing text file and append new letter 
to this file as long as user wants to add new 
letter to the file.

Use while loop
Use fopen (“filename”, “a”);

**I have no idea where to start on this. I understand how to append a single letter, word or phrase to a file, but I have no idea to do the other operation on top of that. Any help is much appreciated.**

OK, so I wanted to work on writing the while loop part separately and just have it print the output to see if I was on the right track...

Here is what I have so far..

What I still need help with is how to end the while loop (by using a specific character)

How to integrate this into the file format and get it to print the characters onto the file.

```css
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int true;
    char mychar;
    char NUL;
    NUL =000;


    while(true)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a letter to append to file A.txt: ");
        scanf(" %c", &mychar);
        if(mychar == (char)000)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so how **do** you add a letter? What keeps you from adding another? What keeps you from doing this in a loop? (no offense, but for basic control structures like loops, please go and read one of the countless tutorials ...)

Comment: I think @FelixPalmen is asking you to show your code so far (and what goes wrong with it).

Comment: @WeatherVane given there *is* some code, then, yes, of course :)

Comment: "I have no idea where to start on this" - then ask your prof for help, we are not a 'do my homework for me' site

Comment: @b-unit: Just to make that clear, my questions are there to give you an idea by thinking about them. People around here will be happy to help you out when you don't know how to go on, but for "don't know how to start" situations, it's really really advisable to read some tutorials instead.

Comment: My professor isn't much help, there is a bit of a language gap to overcome, I'm basically learning from the textbook and my classmates, but at any rate, I've got something I've been working on.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop to achieve this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;

    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("file.txt","a");

    //you can use EOF instead if '\n'
    while( (c = getc(stdin)) != '\n' )
    {
        putc(c,file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```